# Build CSS and JS with the same name but in different folders is been replaced by Vite

Tags: javascript, laravel, sass, vite, laravel-9

So, I have two SCSS files with the same name but inside the different locations

For example:

```
// inside resources

    scss                ---> Folder contains LTR files
      |
      |- a.scss
      |- b.scss
      |- c.scss

    scss-rtl            ---> Folder contains RTL files
      |
      |- a.scss
      |- b.scss
      |- c.scss
```

so the problem is whenever I run `npm run build`

it generates build files but overwrites my previous files

for example :

```
// inside public

build

    assets                ---> overwrites LTR to RTL files
      |
      |- a.[hash].scss
      |- b.[hash].scss
      |- c.[hash].scss
```

Also,

It shows the following message

> The emitted file `"assets/a.c4aecca9.css"` overwrites a previously emitted file of the same name.

Now, I know the file name is same but the folder are different so I think that it should create rtl files hash differently by default.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version Vite (v4.3.9) should have fixed this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34462338)